# pandas datetime columns problem and i don't know what i am missing

Tags: python, pandas

I am a Korean student

Please understand that English is awkward

i want to make columns datetime > year,mounth ....  ,second

```
train = pd.read_csv('input/Train.csv')
```

DateTime looks like this
(this is head(20) and I remove other columns easy to see)

```
    datetime

0   2011-01-01 00:00:00
1   2011-01-01 01:00:00 
2   2011-01-01 02:00:00
3   2011-01-01 03:00:00
4   2011-01-01 04:00:00
5   2011-01-01 05:00:00
6   2011-01-01 06:00:00 
7   2011-01-01 07:00:00
8   2011-01-01 08:00:00
9   2011-01-01 09:00:00
10  2011-01-01 10:00:00
11  2011-01-01 11:00:00
12  2011-01-01 12:00:00
13  2011-01-01 13:00:00
14  2011-01-01 14:00:00
15  2011-01-01 15:00:00
16  2011-01-01 16:00:00
17  2011-01-01 17:00:00
18  2011-01-01 18:00:00
19  2011-01-01 19:00:00
```

then I write this code to see each columns (year,month,day,hour,minute,second)

```
train['year'] = train['datetime'].dt.year

train['month'] = train['datetime'].dt.month

train['day'] = train['datetime'].dt.day

train['hour'] = train['datetime'].dt.hour

train['minute'] = train['datetime'].dt.minute

train['second'] = train['datetime'].dt.seond
```

and error like this

> AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

please help me ㅠㅅㅠ

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: Is your datetime column actually a datetime object? Check out `train['datetime'].dtype`. If it's an `object` or `string`, you can try adding `parse_dates=['datetime']` to the `read_csv` call. Or try `train['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(train['datetime'])` before the `.dt` calls.

Comment: train['datetime'].dtype

Comment: dtype('O').....

Answer (score 0):

Note that by default *read_csv* is able to deduce column type **only**
for numeric and boolean columns.
Unless explicitely specified (e.g. passing *converters* or *dtype*
parameters), all other cases of input are left as **strings**
and the *pandasonic* type of such columns is **object**.

And just this occurred in your case.
So, as this column is of *object* type, you can not invoke *dt* accessor
on it, as it works only on columns of *datetime* type.

Actually, in this case, you can take the following approach:

- do not specify any conversion of this column (it will be parsed
  just as *object*),
- **after** that split *datetime* column into "parts", using *str.split*
  (all 6 columns with a **single** instruction),
- set proper column names in the resulting DataFrame,
- join it to the original DataFrame (then drop),
- as late as now change the type of the original column.

To do it, you can run:

```
wrk = df['datetime'].str.split(r'[- :]', expand=True).astype(int)
wrk.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second']
df = df.join(wrk)
del wrk
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

Note that I added *astype(int)*. Otherwise these columns would be left as
*object* (actually *string*) type.

Or maybe this original column is not needed any more (as you have extracted
all date / time components)? In such case drop this column instead of
converting it.

And the last hint: *datetime* is used rather as a **type name** (with various
endings).
So it is better when you used some other name here, at least differing
in char case, e.g. *DateTime*.